# Tracing the recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I came across this code online and I wanted to trace the recursion. I managed to do so up to:

```
A 
AB
ABC
```

I think I've been doing it wrong.

This is the code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        printAll("ABC", 0, new StringBuffer());
        //      Outputs
        //      ---------
        //      A
        //      AB
        //      ABC
        //      AC
        //      B
        //      BC    
        //      C
    }

    private static void printAll(String str,int start, StringBuffer sb)
    {
        for(int i=start; i< str.length(); i++)
        {
            sb.append(str.charAt(i));
            System.out.println(sb);
            printAll(str, i+1, sb);
            sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you think you went wrong? Is there a more specific question than how to do it? It is easier to correct your understanding if we know what you expect the code to do.

Comment: i just needed to know how to do it.The methodology to trace recursion for this code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple matter of 'unrolling':

The input sequence is `ABC`, so this:

```
for(int i=start; i< str.length(); i++)
{
    sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(sb);
    printAll(str, i+1, sb);
    sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);
}
```

Unrolls to this, with `start` set to 0:

```
sb.append("ABC".charAt(0));
System.out.println(sb);
printAll("ABC", 1, sb); //Recursive call
sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);
sb.append("ABC".charAt(1));
System.out.println(sb);
printAll("ABC", 2, sb); //Recursive call
sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);
sb.append("ABC".charAt(2));
System.out.println(sb);
printAll("ABC", 3, sb); //Recursive call
sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);
```

Given that the length is `3`, we end there. But now we also need to unroll the recursive calls:

```
sb.append("ABC".charAt(0)); // sb="A"
System.out.println(sb);
//Entering recursive call, start=1
    sb.append("ABC".charAt(1));  // sb="AB"
    System.out.println(sb);

    //Entering recursive call, start=2
        sb.append("ABC".charAt(2));  // sb="ABC"
        System.out.println(sb);
        //Enter recursive call, start=3
            // 3 is not less than "ABC".length(), so we leave immediately
        //Exit recursive call
        sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);  // sb="AB"
    //Exit recursive call

    sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);  // sb="A"
    sb.append("ABC".charAt(2));  // sb="AC"
    System.out.println(sb);
    //Enter recursive call, start=3
        // 3 is not less than "ABC".length(), so we leave immediately
    //Exit recursive call
    sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);  // sb="A"
//Exit recursive call

sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);  // sb=""
sb.append("ABC".charAt(1));  // sb="B"
System.out.println(sb);

//Entering recursive call, start=2
    sb.append("ABC".charAt(2));  // sb="BC"
    System.out.println(sb);
    //Enter recursive call, start=3
        // 3 is not less than "ABC".length(), so we leave immediately
    //Exit recursive call
    sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);  // sb="B"
//Exit recursive call

sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);  // sb=""
sb.append("ABC".charAt(2));  // sb="C"
System.out.println(sb);

//Enter recursive call, start=3
    // 3 is not less than "ABC".length(), so we leave immediately
//Exit recursive call

sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);  // sb=""
```

With this fully 'unrolled', we could paste this into a `main` function and execute it, seeing the expected result. You can also walk through what the code is doing at each step, as I have in the comments.

Comment: Though i need to ask why the line sb.append("ABC".charAt(2)); came ?

Comment: The last one? It is the first call of the final for loop.

Comment: No,the one after second exit recursive call

Comment: At that point you are one frame deep into recursion. That function call was made with `start=1`. The previous `sb.append` call (line 4) is made in the first loop of the first recursive call. The call you're referring to is the second loop of the first recursive call, where `start` has been incremented to 2.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a resource, but all you have to do is replace calls to other functions with the function itself, and fill in what the variables are so you can see the actual sequence being executed.